# expect telnet to multiple cisco devices and execute show run

Tags: expect

I have the following scripts which is supposed to pull the IP address from a file `device-list.txt` and then telnet to the device, login and execute a show run. The script logs in to the device successfully, but gives me an error after that. Any ideas where im going wrong?

```
for device in `cat device-list.txt`; do ./test4 $device;done

cat test4
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set hostname [lindex $argv 0]

set user myusername

set pass mypassword

set timeout 10


log_file -a ~/results.log


send_user "\n"

send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"

send_user "\n"


spawn telnet $hostname

expect "Username:"

send "$user\n"

expect "Password:"

send "$pass\n"

expect "#"

send “term len 0\n”

send “show running-config\n”

expect “end\r”

send “\n”

send “exit\n”

User Access Verification

Username: myusername
Password:

ROUTER#usage: send [args] string

    while executing

"send “term len 0\n”"

    (file "./test4" line 26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to incorrect double quotes. You have to use double quotes `"`, not smart quotes `“`

```
send “term len 0\n” ; # Wrong 
send "term len 0\r";  # Correct
```

**Note :**

Basically, `Expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. If `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `Expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.

So, we recommend to use `expect` after each `send`, to make sure our commands actually sent to the spawned process. (You have not used `expect` after sending some commands such as `term len 0\r`). Also, use `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh! I have no idea how those curly brackets got there. I have one more question regarding the script. How would i configure so that i have to manually enter the username and password when the script runs instead of having them saved in the actual script?